# What line break does RCurl return on a mac?

Tags: r

`RCurl` returns different line breaks of an ftp directory on Windows and Linux systems.

```
if(!requireNamespace("RCurl", quietly=TRUE)) install.packages("RCurl")
link <- "ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate"
RCurl::getURL(link, ftp.use.epsv=TRUE, dirlistonly=TRUE)
Sys.info()['sysname'] ; .Platform$OS.type

# Windows / windows: "climate\r\nphenology\r\nradiosondes\r\nclimate_urban\r\n"
# Linux / unix: "climate\nphenology\nradiosondes\nclimate_urban\n"
```

To get a vector of character strings, I can handle both with

```
p <- strsplit(p, "\n")[[1]]
p <- gsub("\r", "", p) # additional carriage return in windows libcurl
```

But: it seems that mac may return `\r` only from the eol explanation in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html. In that case, my approach would fail.

Can someone with a mac test and post the mac (`Sys.info()['sysname']`: "Darwin") output? How about solaris ("SunOS")?

Comment: Or use a regex in strsplit: `"[\\n\\r\\l]"` to split on any carriage return style. This may lead to empty entries in your p list, but this could be filtered after.

Comment: After testing: `"[\r\n]"` would be the correct pattern

Comment: or, y'know `readLines(textConnection(RCurl…))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split on all carriage return, with a regex including both and filter empty entries (cause by \n\r doing two split) after like this:

```
t<-"climate\r\nphenology\r\nradiosondes\r\nclimate_urban\r\n"
t1<-"climate\nphenology\nradiosondes\nclimate_urban\n" 

 p<-unlist(strsplit(t,"[\n\r]"))
 p<-p[nchar(p)>0]

 p1<-unlist(strsplit(t1,"[\n\r]"))
 p1<-p[nchar(p1)>0]
```

Which Gives:

```
> p
[1] "climate"       "phenology"     "radiosondes"   "climate_urban"
> p1
[1] "climate"       "phenology"     "radiosondes"   "climate_urban"
```

Answer (score 0):

A far more succinct, platform agnositc alternative that also uses the `curl` package:

```
library(curl)
readLines(curl(link, handle=new_handle(dirlistonly=TRUE, ftp_use_epsv=TRUE)))
## [1] "hourly"       "daily"        "monthly"      "multi_annual" "subdaily"
```

Comment: Awesome, but in my case (Windows) I get: `Error: FTP: couldn't retrieve (RETR failed) the specified file`

Comment: `readLines()` will work for the `RCurl` call as well. Not enough cycles avail tdy to help debug `curl` & Windows.